# Ordering alphabetically after ordering once numerically

Tags: r, sorting

I have a question relating to R. I have data that looks like this:

```
Name             Value

A                8.0
C                8.1
B                8.1
D                8.2
```

I used `df[order(as.numeric(df[,2])), ]`, which sorted the value column in an ascending order as shown and had the Name column sorted accordingly. However, I would now like to sort the name column alphabetically for repeated values... So since there are two counts of 8.1, I want to lexographically sort B and C.

Comment: `df[order(as.numeric(df[,2]), df$Name), ]`

Comment: If the second column is numeric, you don't need `as.numeric`. ie. `df1[do.call(order, df1[2:1]),]`

Comment: @CathG thanks! Also turns out it was a duplicate